# Angular directive - form/input validation and passing arguments/attributes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation, angularjs-directive

I'm a bit surprised that I haven't found complete solution to this, as it seems to be a common use case:

I need help with crating custom angular directive. What I have is a form with basic front-end-side validation and messages in `<span>` which appear on submit.

I have simple form with validation:
[jsbin sample](https://jsbin.com/juxeho/edit?html,output)

What I want to achieve:

- Things like `ng-max-length`, `ng-min-length`, `ng-pattern`, `ng-model` etc. shouldn't be hard-coded inside of the template, rather passed as arguments from my custom-tag to the inside of directive's template - and assigned to the `<input>` element. (even fancier would be to assign some of the attributes to `input` and some other for example inside of `label` so that directives template can contain not only the input, but a bit bigger part of HTML, including the label)
- two kinds of validation - one by highlighting the fields basing on the classes (no problem with that), second one with `<span>` elements appearing on submit

What problems am I facing?

1. How to pass the arguments (attributes) from my custom-tag to the input inside of the template?
2. I have now in one HTML file: `formName.inputName.$error.typeOfError`; How to achieve that now from the inside of the directive/template? Somehow parameterizing it.
3. Regarding showing validation messages on submit: Is the variable `submitted` set when pressing submit button and cleared when resetting the form a good idea or there is a nicer solution to that?
4. Make the scopes isolated so multiple instances of the directive do not interfere with each other.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: You should probably narrow your question a bit. Feels like there is 4 questions smashed into 1. Hard to give a complete answer to.

Comment: Isn't it a reasonable use case of a form validation and if we find answer something reusable in the future? :) I have a feeling that it can be done pretty easily in angular, but I'm quite new (to angular) and what I produced not only doesn't look nice, but also doesn't meet all of my requirements... Anyway. partial answers are welcome as well! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The docs for creating angular directives don't really give examples but what you need is the scope property defined.

Check the following:
https://jsbin.com/zabuza/edit?html,js,output

Also, be very careful with using input[number], caused me major headache in this example as it's not a normal ng type of directive.

Docs I used:
[docs1](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)
[docs2](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)